# Every "go" command leads to a panic from a certain main.go

Tags: go

I've noticed that every `go` command has stopped working, due to a panic from a `main.go` in a particular module:

```
> go env
panic: required key FOO missing value

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig.MustProcess(...)
    /Users/kurtpeek/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig@v1.4.0/envconfig.go:233
main.main()
    /Users/kurtpeek/go/pkg/mod/github.com/myorg/mymodule/go@v0.0.0-20210129234103-92f90e2df5c0/main.go:13 +0x314
```

where the 'offending' main go is similar to

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
    "github.pie.apple.com/someorg/somemodule/config"
)

func main() {
    cfg := &config.Config{}
    envconfig.MustProcess("", cfg)
}
```

I have no idea why a `go env` command should fail for this reason?

Comment: Does `go env` and co. work normally once you remove the offending code? e.g. comment out the imports and main's body?

Comment: seems like there are corrupted packages in import section

Comment: Did you install this program under the name "go" by accident, so that it doesn't actually run the tool chain? What does `type go` output?

Comment: `go env` does not look at the local project. It is just printing the GoLang env vars.
I would imagine your env vars got messed up somehow. If you open a new terminal and run `go env`, does it then work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module is called `github.com/myorg/mymodule/go`, which means that the installed binary is called "go" (after the last path segment). This binary likely shadows the go tool depending on how your PATH is configured.

I suggest you change the module path to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to reinstall go as it seems that somehow the binary for go env command is replaced by a binary you were potentially trying to compile, possible reason could be you built the program in the directory containing the go tools. I recommend reinstalling go